# With AWS Lex, Is there a way to find out which intent slot value Lex is tying to fill , using lambda code hooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm new to AWS lex and I want to use AWS lex to accept long sentences and certain application-specific phrases that don't fit in any of the default or custom slot types I tried. The only workaround I can think of is to use the 'inputTranscript' property from the 'event' object which is passed from lex to lambda code hooks and replace the slot value of the slot lex is trying to fill with the inputTranscript value. For that, I couldn't find a proper way to find out which slot the lex is trying to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use case, I think you can use Aws lex regex slots feature where you can give you custom regex to indentify phrases.